# I am trying to use C to read a .csv file but I'm concerned by the codeblocks watch display

Tags: c, csv, codeblocks

This my first C program (beyond "Hello World").  I am trying to read a csv file created by Excel.  I think it works because my printing seems right but I am concerned about how the codeblocks watch window displays my variables.  Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<String.h>
void getData(char *buff);
char word[1024][18];
char device[1024][128];
char action [1024][64];
char YN[1024][10];
int messageNumber=0;
int numMessages=0;
int main()
{
    const char filename[] = "Messages.csv";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    char buff[1024];
    while( fgets(buff, 1024, (FILE*)fp))
    { 
       //reads to 1024-1 or \n or EOL
       numMessages++;
       if(numMessages != 1) //Throw away the header row.
       {
            getData(buff);
            messageNumber++;
       }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<numMessages;i++)
    {
       printf("%s %s %s %s",word[i],device[i],action[i],YN[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp); 
    getch();  //get one character.  Sort of pause before closing the         window
}
void getData(char buff[])
{
   char *token = strtok(buff,",");  
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
        strcpy(&word[messageNumber][0],token);
        token = strtok(NULL,","); //NULL means return from buff what is between  
                                //  the previous "," and the next "," then 
                                // point to the next ",".
        strcpy(&device[messageNumber][0],token);
        token = strtok(NULL,",");
        strcpy(&action[messageNumber][0],token);
        token = strtok(NULL,",");
        strcpy(&YN[messageNumber][0],token);
        token = strtok(NULL,",");
   }    
}
```

The csv file is:

Word,Device,Action,Xmit

FF7FB5E6D2203A04,BackDoor,Open,N

FF7FB5E6D2213708,BackDoor,Close,N

FF7FB5E6D200BB09,BackDoor,Closing,Y

(I don't know how to upload it)

When I run codeblocks in Debug mode I get the followingI
[image: CodeBlocksWatch]

My question is, why are my variables displayed so differently?

**Word** seems to have only the first two lines indexed and the third seems to be in the index field.

**device** seems to all be on the same row as does **action**

**YN** seems the closest to "right"
When I print the variables they seem right but the watch window display bothers me.  Am I OK? (first timer for C)

Comment: Why does `getData` have a while-loop *at all* ? I.e. `getData` is already being called per-line from `main` and you're already pulling apart the line item-by-item; that loop is pointless.

Comment: Well, first of all, probably because I don't know what I am doing.  But at one point I was doing something that seemed to cause my program to keep going through buff to the end so I put this in to stop that after the line I wanted.  Do you think that is causing the variation in the variables in the watch?

Comment: Using that debugger you can set a breakpoint on the first line within that function, then step through it, including the unnecessary loop. I think you'll see what is happening.

Comment: OK, I removed the "while" and confirmed that it is not needed. Thanks!

Comment: Then I found something interesting.  Doing the breakpoint/step, I found that the way the watch window displays variables seems to be related to the difference between the number of characters in the field relative to the memory allocated.  For example, at first it was YN[1024][10] and displayed as shown in my post.  I changed it to  YN[1024][50] and it displayed as the variables "device" and "action" are displayed.  I suppose I could do a binary search to find the value that trips the change but....I have better things to do with my life.  Thanks

Comment: Kamil Cuk.  I see you deleted the four spaces before each line.  I originally copied and pasted from the codeblocks window and it looked exactly as your edited version but when I tried to post it I was refused because it said I needed four characters before each line.  So I went back and pasted four more spaces before each line (total 8 or more) and then I could post it.   Who knows??????????